# Visual Studio How to use C++ standard library in a kernel mode driver project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, driver, kmdf

I'm using vs2015 and wdk10, I can use **random** in an empty project .

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine eng;//works fine .
```

But when I create an empty kernel mode driver project ,I can't use **random** in  it.

```
#include <random>
std::default_random_engine eng;//namespace "std" has no member "default_random_engine"
```

Other standard libraries ,like **vector** and **tuple** wouldn't work either , all reminding me that **namespace "std" has no member XXX** (vector ,tuple ,etc .)

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You cannot. You don't have the privilege of using such stuff in kernel mode.

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal ,How should I generate random numbers then ?

Comment: @iouvxz Check `RtlRandomEx()`

Comment: @Gaurav Sehgal OK ,thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The implementation of the std library requires working exception processing for the code to work correctly.  That has stopped a port of the standard library from being performed in kernel.

Other examples of code which does not work in kernel, is

- magic statics (thread safe initialization of local variables - requires thread-local-storage, which is not in kernel).
- static initialization of objects.  In a DLL or EXE, the global data of a program is initialized by the runtime before main is called.  That code is not present in the kernel
- stack size.  A kernel thread is only 12kb of memory, which makes some algorithms choke, causing exceptions.
- Memory handling is different in kernel, with memory being allocated with a Tag.  That would be lost,  or create interfacing issues if you implemented an allocator with a tag.

As mentioned in the comments

```
RtlRandomEx
```

produces pseudo random numbers, and is available in kernel.

For cryptographic secure randomness, then this page holds some value.

[MS crypto primatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/seccng/cryptographic-primitives)